# Error when trying to use alternative update method in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I'm having a hard time trying to track down an error. I'm using a separate update method for changing my users passwords when their logged in. I've posted the code below.

In users_controller:

```
def change_password
      @user = current_user
      @user_password_matches = User.authenticate(current_user.email, params[:current_password])
      if @user_password_matches.update_attributes(params[:user])
        login @user
        format.js   { render :js => "window.location = '#{settings_account_path}'" } 
        flash[:success] = "Password updated" 
      else
        format.js   { render :form_errors }

      end
    end
```

Inside view:

```
<%= form_for @user, :remote => true, change_password_path(@user) do |f| %>
Current password: <%= password_field_tag :current_password, :placeholder => "Password"  %><br />
New password: <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Password"  %><br />
Confirm password: <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :placeholder => "Confirm Password"  %><br />
<%= f.submit 'update' %>
```

routes:

```
resources :users do
  member do
    put :change_password
  end
end
  resources :users
  resources :sessions
  resources :passwords
  resources :profiles


  root :to                   => "users#new"
  match 'success'            => "users#success"
  match 'login'              => "sessions#new"
  match 'logout'             => "sessions#destroy"
  match 'reset_password'     => "passwords#new"
  match 'setup_new_password' => "passwords#edit"
  match 'settings', :to      => "users#settings"


  match "/settings/account", :to => "users#account"
  match "/settings/edit_profile", :to => "profiles#edit_profile"


  match '/:username', :controller => 'users', :action => 'show'
```

Error:

```
SyntaxError in Users#account

Showing /Users/greg/site/app/views/users/account.html.erb where line #27 raised:

/Users/greg/site/app/views/users/account.html.erb:27: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting tASSOC
...> true, change_password_path do |f| @output_buffer.safe_conc...
...                               ^
/Users/greg/site/app/views/users/account.html.erb:51: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end
Extracted source (around line #27):

24:     </div>
25: <h3><a href="#">Change Password</a></h3>
26:     <div>
27:         <p> <%= form_for @user, :remote => true, change_password_path do |f| %>
28: Current password: <%= password_field_tag :current_password, :placeholder => "Password"  %><br />
29: New password: <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Password"  %><br />
30: Confirm password: <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :placeholder => "Confirm Password"  %><br />
```

I'm sure the problem is coming from my form and routes, can any one help me with a solution to make this work?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the following view snippet:

```
<%= form_for @user, :remote => true, change_password_path(@user) do |f| %>
```

Try to replace it with:

```
<%= form_for @user, :remote => true, :url => change_password_path(@user) do |f| %>
```

Comment: That solved that first issue now I'm getting: Routing Error

No route matches {:controller=>"users", :action=>"change_password", :format=>#<User id: 1, email: "foo@bar.baz", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$lgmrRTYFUUrWStLl1Y.Oo.LqQ2Ybxa29YkDFw61/KG9O...", password_salt: "$2a$10$lgmrRTYFUUrWStLl1Y.Oo.", username: "foobar", created_at: "2012-01-07 23:02:29", updated_at: "2012-01-13 11:16:45", password_reset_token: nil, password_reset_sent_at: "2012-01-08 12:23:30">}

Comment: Do you have `change_password` method in your `UsersController`? If you do so, then is it enabled in your `routes.rb`?

Comment: Maybe that's a `POST` not a `PUT`, you're updating, not creating, aren't you?